# how to parse a JSON from file?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have a basic question, but I can't make this work for an android app.
I have a JSON file that looks like this:

```
{  
  "catches":[  
    {  
      "time":"Jan 14, 2021 10:40:04 PM",
      "amount":1,
      "condition":0.8
    },
    {  
      "time":"Jan 15, 2021 12:05:14 PM",
      "amount":"2",
      "condition":1.0
    },
    {  
      "time":"Jan 16, 2021 11:30:04 PM",
      "amount":"3",
      "condition":null
    }
  ]
}
```

How could I parse the JSON from a file stored in internal storage and assign the values to variables?
In C# I could do something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string fPath = "C:/Temp/myJSON.json";
            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(fPath))
            {
                string json = r.ReadToEnd();
                Root el;
                el = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);

                //variable which later would be used in for a TextView
                var lastRecord = el.catches[el.catches.Count - 1].time;
            } 
        }
```

But I don't know how to make something like this in java. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the file content as string:

```
fun getDataAsStringFromPath(path: String): String {
    val file = File(this.javaClass.classLoader?.getResource(path)?.path)

    return file.readText(Charset.defaultCharset())
  }
```

Make sure you save this file in `resources` directory at the same place where `res` lies.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you look at a JSON parsing library. The one I recommend is Jackson. It is quite easy to parse the String to your object.
First,y ou create a Data class. In your example, you will need two: CacheItem and Container (rename appropriately if you feel like it)

```
class CacheItem {
    private String time;
    private Integer amount;
    private Double condition;
    
    // Getters and Setters
}

class Container {
    private List<CacheItem> caches;
    // Getter and Setter
}
```

Now, where you want to parse the String from the file, get the Object Mapper (see Jackson API for this) and simply call `Container container = mapper.readValue(string, Container.class);`